# Weaker version of forth condition in bisimulation

Tags: logic, relations, modal-logic

In bisimulation as used in modal logic part of the structure is this:

Suppose there are sets $W_1, W_2$ each supporting a binary relation $R_i \subseteq W_i \times W_i$ for $i = 1,2$, and that $Z \subseteq W_1 \times W_2$. Then $Z$ is said to satisfy the forth condition provided
$Z R_1^{-1} \subseteq R_2^{-1} Z$ and $Z$ is said to satisfy the back condition provided
$R_2 Z \subseteq Z R_1 $.

I am interested in a weaker version of the forth condition:

Given any $(w_1, v_1) \in R_1$ such that there is some $(v_1, v_2) \in Z$,
then for each $(w_1, w_2) \in Z$ there is some $u \in W_2$ such that
$(v_1, u) \in Z$ and $(w_2,u) \in R_2$.

The following diagram shows elements $w_1, v_1, v_2, w_2, u$ and some pairs in the relations.

[image: Diagram showing the elements involved]

I am tempted to say "existential forth" or maybe "domain-restricted forth" in view of:

It is equivalent to defining a relation $D \subseteq W_1 \times W_1$ (the domain of $Z$) as the subrelation of the identity
where $(w,w)\in D$ iff there is some $(w,v') \in Z$ and then asking that
$$Z R_1^{-1} D \subseteq R_2^{-1} Z.$$

**Question:**
Is this condition known anywhere? Does it have an accepted name?

Comment: I have nothing to contribute to this interesting question (very much not my field), but you may want to check this [post on meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16888/329252) for this type of diagrams.

Comment: thank you - helpful to know that about diagrams

Comment: Your construction could be related to operations that were used before the bisimulation concept was isolated. Specifically it could be related to what is nowadays known as bounded morphisms or p-morphisms (Goldblatt's term), which also have 'existential parts'. But I doubt that your construction yields invariance results for modal languages. If so, the the point of the construction is not obvious, at least not from a modal perspective.